# Minted package causing Error with "ifplatform.sty" and "minted.sty"

Tags: errors, packages, minted

Always as i try to load

> \packages{minted}

i get the following error:

[image]

Minted is up to date, Anaconda with Pygmentize is installed, the paths and "pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex" are set.

I do not even know whats going wrong. Without the Package there is no error and no warning.

EDIT: I´ve tried it with

> \packages{pythontex}

and got a similuar error:

[image]

UPDATE: \usepackage{minted} works now, but now I get with this example:

[image]

this:

[image]

ONES AGAIN: I deleted all temporary files and now IT WORKS!

Comment: Show the log-file of a minimal (!) example that loads minted.

Comment: I gave u an short example down there. :)

Comment: I wrote  show the *log* file. Also don't add info as answer edit you question.

Comment: ok, sorry... with an minimal example it works. :/ i will check which package influences the minted package badly and report it later.

Comment: ok i deactivated package by package and figured out that the error comes in combination with "ngerman" and "minted". if i do it with babel like: \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} there is no error anymore.

Comment: ngerman should not be used.

Comment: just delete it or replace it by an alternative?

Comment: As you did: use babel with the ngerman option.

Comment: ok thanks, now there is the an other problem... XD i will edit my post... sorry for so much "trouble" :D

Comment: ONES AGAIN: I deleted all temporary files and now IT WORKS! Thanks @ all :)